Loop through variables not through an Array
I need loop through all the variables. But it doesn't work.
$var0='a'
$var1='b'
$var2='c'

$i=0; While ($i -lt 3) { 
$var[$i]
$i++}


Most popular is
$var=('a','b','c')
$i=0; While ($i -lt 3) {
$var[$i]
$i++}

and it works.
But I need loop variables, was shown in the first block

Do you just want to read the variable contents, or do you need to modify them too?

What is it actually what you're trying to do? Most of the time it is not necessary to loop through a bunch of variables. If you insist you could enumerate the variables with getting the content of the drive variable: with a filter for the names you choose ...

Thank you. I need mofify variabled too.  And how to use drive as "variable:" ? for example

How would you list the content of the drive c: for example?   ...  Get-ChildItem -Path variable:  ... but again ... what is it what you're actually trying to do? I'm almost sure there is a better way.

Sorry, I misunderstood you. It's not the disk. These are just variables

I need to use a loop to get names: $var0, $var1, Var2 ... And then get values from variables

Try (get-variable "var$i”).Value, although as others have said, looping through variables is often an indicator that there’s a better data structure to be using, like an array / hashtable…

Get-ChildItem -Path variable: | Where-Object -Property Name -Like -Value var* ... ‍♂️ ... but again ... what is it what you're actually trying to do? You're probably doing something wrong ... or at least way more cumbersome than necessary.

Cases like this is where a hashtable is just better, $variables = @{ var0 = 'a'; var1 = 'b'; ... } then  $variables.GetEnumerator() | % { $varname = $_.Key; $varvalue = $_.Value ... }

What you're looking for is variable indirection, where you refer to a variable indirectly, via its name stored in a different variable or provided by an expression. PowerShell enables this via the Get-Variable and Set-Variable cmdlets, but note that there are usually better alternatives, such as hashtables. See the linked duplicates for details.

You can do this:
$var0='a'
$var1='b'
$var2='c'

$ThisVar = 'var1'
Get-Variable -Name $ThisVar -ValueOnly

Which in turn means you can do this:
$var0='a'
$var1='b'
$var2='c'

$i=0; While ($i -lt 3) {
$ThisVar = "var$i"
Get-Variable -Name $ThisVar -ValueOnly
$i++}

And this:
$var0='a'
$var1='b'
$var2='c'

$i=0; While ($i -lt 3) {
Get-Variable -Name "var$i" -ValueOnly
$i++}


Fantastic! Thank you! As a result I did: (Get-Variable -Name $ThisVar).name
